# Inverting SMPS - tantalum and part selection | Monolithic controller getting hot

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, review

I'm designing a circuit to provide a negative voltage rail in a battery for an ADC. I've decided to use a particular monolithic [BCD Chip](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AZ34063U.pdf) that can work as a step up/down/inverting controller and has an integrated switch.

I've designed the circuit inline with the data sheet inverting reference with the exception of using tantalums, a different shottky (30V 1A) and have a higher input voltage. At this point it doesn't appear that the circuit is switching (at all) from what I can tell, there is no oscillation on the timing cap pin or output, and Vout is measuring around +.3V. The chip is commanding 3W of energy which it appears to be dissipating itself.

Have I missed something here. I've substituted all components, so this is likely a design or layout issue I think. [image][image]

Comment: What is driving VCC, ie what is HYST_OUT? Then : if it's dissipating 4* the Abs Max power for the package, it's completely dead, and everything you can measure stems from that. Next time, power it from a supply current-limited to 50 or 100mA...

Comment: HYST_OUT is the input - I am using a current limited supply, that was max observed

Comment: I'm not sure you could have made that schematic any more confusing!

Answer (score 0):

R5,R6 are connected incorrectly thus feedback voltage does not match 1.25V.

1 cut 2 jumpers needed. It should be obvious.

Comment: How so? Are they not identical to that in the reference? Are you seeing that on the schematic or the layout? Edit | I see it, the 12V reference is on the output of the voltage divider. Thanks for that :)